# How to redirect a fully encoded url htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect http://www.site1.com/%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C/%D7%AA%D7%9C-%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9

to

http://www.site2.com/history

Tried many different rules, bot non worked.

Need help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_rewrite unencode the url so you can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule "הגליל/תל-קדש" http://site2.com/history [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this did work (it was neglected)

Comment: I had it working on my test machine. Make sure you safe the htaccess using utf-8 encoding.